# Show preview in another view page in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am registering some data into a form which is quite large. Now I want to see the preview of the given data into another tab before submit the form . How can i do this by ajax?

I am using serialize() to pass the data into ajax url, and I can fetch the data at the controller, but the problem is how i can show the data into another view page?

here is my ajax:

```
 var postdata = jQuery('#job_form_post').serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/job_controller/job_post_view_before_submit",
        data : postdata,
        async : false,
       // datatype: "json",
        success: function(response){


     }
        });
```

The ajax is called on click event of a button on the register page. Actually i am confused about the use of datatype and success response in this purpose.

In my controller function I can fetch the data and put them into an array named $data.  Then I am using the line:

```
$this->load->view('employee/job_post_view_before_submit', $data); exit();
```

That means I want to show the data into a view page named 'job_post_view_before_submit'. But nothing works at this time.

Can you please help me to do this by ajax.Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to using by bootstrap.wizard nav tab. Or you want to display data in another page.

Step 1:first page form action to next page without insert functionality.

Step 2: In second page use the value from first page in 'hidden' field or in session and print that values with submit button, when you click submit button goes to inserting functionality in controller/model.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to have a modal window (if you are using bootstrap for example) or a tab in the same page (if you are able to have different tabs) that could act as a confirmation window. Then all you have to do is following the completion of the form data capture (and before submission) is to call a js function to iterate through the form fields - pick up the data entered and display it to the user. This modal could then have a confirm button that acts as your trigger to submit the form via AJAX. If the user wants to edit any detail - dismissthe modal - navigate to the required field - edit the content  and re-confirm the data entry. Then submit the form as you would normally. This way its all in the one page - allows re-editing and confirmation  and also client side validation prior to submission.